# Mapping objects and their names in an array with loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping

I've got an array with some objects :

```
var myArray = [{
    'id': 'first',
    'value': 'firstValue'
}, {
    'id': 'second',
    'value': 'secondValue'
}, {
    'id': 'third',
    'value': 'thirdValue'}, 
etc.];
```

I'm trying to add values with a loop so that I have something like this :

```
var myArray = [{
    'id': 'first',
    'value': 'firstValue',
    'inc1' : 1
}, {
    'id': 'second',
    'value': 'secondValue'
    'inc2' : 2
}, {
    'id': 'third',
    'value': 'thirdValue'
    'inc3' : 3
}];
```

I know that with mapping

```
myArray.forEach(function(o, i) { 
    o.inc = i + 1;                 
});
```

I can get the results incremented, but how do I get the names inc1, inc2, inc3...?

Comment: Just curious: Why do you want to add the number to the property name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use bracket notation for the property as [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors), like

> ```
> object.property    // dot notation
> object['property'] // bracket notation
> ```

```js
var myArray = [{ id: 'first', value: 'firstValue' }, { id: 'second', value: 'secondValue' }, { id: 'third', value: 'thirdValue' }];

myArray.forEach(function (o, i) {
    o['inc' + (i + 1)] = i + 1;
    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ use brackets and property as string
});

console.log(myArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```